# Operand data type date is invalid for subtract operator

Tags: sql-server, function

I have a field in my table called `[LastDate] with DataType Date`. and I am going to write a function which compute  the `[LastDate]-@PassedParameter`, but the error happen :

```
Operand data type date is invalid for subtract operator.
```

I don't know why?

hara is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Salman( @Date  date )
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[LastDate]
      ,[Rule]
      ,[CoA]
  FROM [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[Group]
  where ([LastDate]-@Date)%[Rule]=0  
)
GO
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try using the [DATEDIFF function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189794.aspx).

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

So in your case you may change like this:

```
where DATEDIFF(dd,LastDate,@Date)%[Rule]=0
               ^^--Change this to mm,qq whatever you want.
```

Comment: if he is trying to do `[LastDate]-@Date` shouldn't we consider that `@Date` = DATEDIFFS's `stardate`?; thus the query would be `where DATEDIFF(dd,@Date,LastDate)%[Rule]=0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Salman( @Date  date )
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
  ,[Name]
  ,[LastDate]
  ,[Rule]
  ,[CoA]
FROM [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[Group]
where (Datediff(dd,[LastDate],@Date))%[Rule]=0  
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the format of your two dates is not exactly the same.  This should work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Salman( @Date  date )
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

SELECT TOP 1000 [ID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[LastDate]
      ,[Rule]
      ,[CoA]
  FROM [Scheduling_Employee].[dbo].[Group]
  where (cast([LastDate] as datetime)-cast(@Date as datetime))%[Rule]=0  
)
GO
```