# how to calculate average date between two tables?

Tags: sql

```
select t.TransCode, avg(d.SetupDate - t.MonthPosted) as avgdate
from Debtor as D
join Trans as T
    on T.DebtorNo = D.LogonID
where t.TransCode in ('411', '412', '413', '416') 
group by t.TransCode
```

I am getting

> Operand data type date is invalid for subtract operator.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: what is meant by average date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operand data type date is invalid for subtract operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450740/operand-data-type-date-is-invalid-for-subtract-operator)

Comment: It looks like the first date `d.SetupDate` is a date and the second (`t.MonthPosted`) is just a month. These won't give you a valid result. You would have to subtract the `tMonthPosted` from the month in `d.SetupDate`.